# Неверный подсчет определителя произвольной матрицы

Tags: javascript, математика, матрицы

Функция `det2by2(m)` вычисляет определитель матрицы 2x2, функция `detNbyN(m)` вычисляет определитель матрицы любого размера. Функция `minor(m, num)` вычисляет минор матрицы, здесь `num` - индекс числа первой строки матрицы. Определитель матрицы в конце кода должен быть равен 62, но в консоль выводится 48, предположительное проблемное место помечено *. Как нужно изменить код, чтобы он правильно считал определитель?

```js
function determinant(m) {
  function det2by2(m) {
    return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];
  }

  function detNbyN(m) {
    const firstRow = m[0];
    if (firstRow.length === 2) return det2by2(m);

    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      sum += firstRow[i] * (-1) ** 2 + i * detNbyN(minor(m, i)); // *
    }
    return sum;
  }

  function minor(m, num) {
    const m1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m));
    m1.splice(0, 1);
    for (let elem of m1) {
      elem.forEach((el, i) => {
        if (i === num) elem.splice(i, 1);
      });
    }
    return m1;
  }

  if (m.length === 1) return m[0][0];
  if (m.length === 2) return det2by2(m);
  if (m.length >= 3) return detNbyN(m);
};

console.log(determinant(
  [
    [2, 4, 2, 2],
    [3, 1, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0, 2],
    [3, 4, 5, 6]
  ]
)); // **
```

Comment: `i * detNbyN(minor(m, i))` вот это явная лажа. Не может индекс использоваться в вычислениях как самостоятельное число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не уверен, что в JavaScript оператор `**` выполняет возведение в степень. Воспользуемся функцией `Math.pow`.
2. Формула расчёта элемента суммы у вас записана неправильно. При разложении матрицы по строке знаки должны чередоваться, начиная с плюса. То есть множитель перед элементом строки и минором должен быть равен `(-1)^(i)`, где `i=0, 1, 2...`.

```
  function detNbyN(m) {
    const firstRow = m[0];
    if (firstRow.length === 2) return det2by2(m);

    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      sum += firstRow[i] * Math.pow(-1, i) * detNbyN(minor(m, i)); // *
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Если ещё есть какие-то проблемы, связанные с языком, то тут я уже не помощник. Функцию `minor` проверить не могу, в ней используются особые функции JS.

Comment: Насчет первого, то вот [Exponentiation (**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Может вы хотели написать

```js
sum += firstRow[i] * ((-1) ** (2 + i)) * detNbyN(minor(m, i));
```

хотя вообще лучше написать как в учебнике:

```js
sum += Math.pow(-1, i) * firstRow[i] * detNbyN(minor(m, i));
```

— однозначно, понятно и не нужно мучаться расстановкой скобочек.